# Troubles with scanf function (C)

Tags: c, monodevelop, scanf

I have the following code:

```
struct punto richiedi_punto () {
static int count=1;
struct punto point;

do {
printf("Inserire coordinate del punto %i:", count);
scanf("%d;%d",&point.x,&point.y);

} while (point.x<0 || point.x>9 || point.y<0 || point.y>9);
count++;

return point;
}
```

Gcc doesn't find errors, but I get this warning:

```
Warning: ignoring return value of ‘scanf’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
```

I tried to find out a solution on google, but I didn't understand what causes this warning.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I noticed just now that if I run my program in MonoDevelop console, I cannot insert my coordinates (why?), but if I run it in gnome-terminal it works normally.

Comment: Remove `;` from scanf (between the 2 %d's)

Comment: what is type of x and y? can you give full code?

Comment: @CoolGuy: It creates problems, like this one: http://ideone.com/SL6Ido

Comment: @karma_geek , Without that, the `scanf` fails when input is something like `3;2`. You can't say that it needs to be removed. Besides, once the `return` value if `scanf` is checked(and proper action is taken), everything will be alright

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf()` returns the number of fields successfully converted, for you to check

```
int fields;
do {
    printf("Inserire coordinate del punto %i:", count);
    fields = scanf("%d;%d",&point.x,&point.y);
} while (fields != 2 || point.x<0 || point.x>9 || point.y<0 || point.y>9);
```

As @chux points out, the above is not good. Here is a version using `sscanf` instead of `scanf`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int fields, x, y;
    char inp[100];
    do {
        printf("Inserire coordinate:");
        fgets(inp, 100, stdin);
        fields = sscanf(inp, "%d;%d",&x,&y);
    } while (fields != 2 || x<0 || x>9 || y<0 || y>9);
    printf("x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `while (fields != 2 || point.x<0 ....` is the start of a good idea, but handling `fields != 2` likely needs a different path then looping.  User input like "12 x 34" would cause an infinite loop.

Comment: @chux that is why I hate `scanf`.

Comment: We could hope next rev of C will send `gets()` a companion called `scanf()`?

Comment: ... into the deprecated bin.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [scanf manual](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) : the return value of the function is the only way for you to know if the function succeed.

Here, your compiler doesn't like your code because you don't even look at the return value, so your code will continue even if the function failed.

A failure here is very easy, for instance if the input are not number, or doesn't contain a ';' as expected, or others.

So just replacing the scanf line by something like :

```
if (scanf("%d;%d",&point.x,&point.y) != 2)) {}
```

Should reassure Gcc, showing him you care about return values.
But the cleanest solution would be to stock the return value and to do something depending of, look at the "return value" part of the manual for more information.

Answer (score -1):

`Scanf` return the value that no.of input get from the user successfully. Warning is you are ignoring that return value.

So you can use like this,

```
int ret;
ret=scanf("%d;%d",&point.x,&point.y);
```

Or else,

```
(void*)scanf("%d;%d",&point.x,&point.y);
```

Answer (score -1):

It means that you do not check the return value of scanf. 
scanf can return 1 if only point.x or point.y is set or return 0 if neither point.x or point.y is set.

you can check return value of scanf to remove this warning like that

```
int ret = scanf("%d;%d",&point.x,&point.y);
if (ret != 2) 
{
    printf("Error whith scanf");
    return 0;
}
```